# i use pressure from a running water hose for masturbation.Do i need to do ghusl?

Tags: halal-haram, women, ghusl, masturbation, fatwa-explanation

is this masturbate? but I didn't touch my vagina. I tried to hard to get rid of this and please help me.

Comment: GHUSL is required. We have tons of questions on this topic. A quick search on this site and you will have the answer. Please take a look at the help center article on [How to ask a good question?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Clicking on the tag `masturbation` will help you out alot!

Answer (score -1):

stop thinking about your habits and try not doing it and if you still do it pray 2 rakah for forgiveness which will help you by protecting from shaitan who is making you do it. so if you pray two rakah then the shaitan will be fed up on you and say don't pray don't pray and he will realise that bcoz of him who is making you do your bad habit is making you pray. So try this trick and hope it will work and thank you..